# How to check my device time is in which timezone?

Tags: ios, swift4

I am getting timeStamp from API as EST, if my device is in India or in USA  then it should show (IST or CST) the time according to the timezone. How can I do it?

```
let currentTimeZone = formatter.timeZone.identifier
print(currentTimeZone) // Asia/Kolkata
```

How can I get EST, CST, EDT, etc. instead of getting Asia/Kolkata?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name from the name property:

```
 NSLog(@"Name : %@", timeZone.name);
```

Output will be :

```
2015-07-10 13:31:46.292 APP[2904:50429] Name : Asia/Calcutta
```

Then You can to get the name with the desired style:

```
NSTimeZone* timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"IST"];
NSString* timeZoneName = [timeZone localizedName:NSTimeZoneNameStyleStandard locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSLog(@"Name : %@", timeZoneName);

NSLog(@"%@",[NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]);
```

output will be:

```
2015-07-10 11:44:05.954 APP[1472:26120] {
    ADT = "America/Halifax";
    AKDT = "America/Juneau";
    AKST = "America/Juneau";
    ART = "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires";
    AST = "America/Halifax";
    BDT = "Asia/Dhaka";
    BRST = "America/Sao_Paulo";
    BRT = "America/Sao_Paulo";
    BST = "Europe/London";
    CAT = "Africa/Harare";
    CDT = "America/Chicago";
    CEST = "Europe/Paris";
    CET = "Europe/Paris";
    CLST = "America/Santiago";
    CLT = "America/Santiago";
    COT = "America/Bogota";
    CST = "America/Chicago";
    EAT = "Africa/Addis_Ababa";
    EDT = "America/New_York";
    EEST = "Europe/Istanbul";
    EET = "Europe/Istanbul";
    EST = "America/New_York";
    GMT = GMT;
    GST = "Asia/Dubai";
    HKT = "Asia/Hong_Kong";
    HST = "Pacific/Honolulu";
    ICT = "Asia/Bangkok";
    IRST = "Asia/Tehran";
    IST = "Asia/Calcutta";
    JST = "Asia/Tokyo";
    KST = "Asia/Seoul";
    MDT = "America/Denver";
    MSD = "Europe/Moscow";
    MSK = "Europe/Moscow";
    MST = "America/Denver";
    NZDT = "Pacific/Auckland";
    NZST = "Pacific/Auckland";
    PDT = "America/Los_Angeles";
    PET = "America/Lima";
    PHT = "Asia/Manila";
    PKT = "Asia/Karachi";
    PST = "America/Los_Angeles";
    SGT = "Asia/Singapore";
    UTC = UTC;
    WAT = "Africa/Lagos";
    WEST = "Europe/Lisbon";
    WET = "Europe/Lisbon";
    WIT = "Asia/Jakarta";
}
```

then you can find what is your current timezone.

Comment: can you convert it to swift 4

Answer (score 0):

```
let timeStr = "15/02/2014 01:00:00"

let currentTimezone = TimeZone.current
let targetTimezone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST") ?? TimeZone.current

let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

let localOffset = currentTimezone.secondsFromGMT()
let targetOffset = targetTimezone.secondsFromGMT()


let localDate = dateFormatter1.date(from: timeStr)


let targetDate = localDate?.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(targetOffset - localOffset))
```

Try this. `TimeZone.current` will return you the current timezone used by system.

Comment: use timeZone.abbrevation()

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
let timeZone = TimeZone.current
let name = timeZone.localizedName(for: .shortStandard, locale: Locale.current)
print("Name :: ", name)
```

Comment: let gm =   Calendar.current.timeZone.abbreviation()! ,
 print(gm) ,it is also showing same output

Comment: just tell me how to print EST,CST etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.It works for me.

Please get the time from server from UTC format.
then :

```
func convertFromUTCtoLocal(dateToConvert:String) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"
    let convertedDate = formatter.date(from: dateToConvert)
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    return formatter.string(from: convertedDate!)
}
```

Set the timezone according to your requirement.It may helps to you. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

ObjC:

```
NSTimeZone *timeZoneLocal = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSString *strTimeZoneAbb = [timeZoneLocal abbreviation];
NSString *strTimeZoneName = [timeZoneLocal name];
NSLog(@"%@",strTimeZoneAbb);  //Ex:Output:GMT +5:10
NSLog(@"%@",strTimeZoneName);  //Ex:Output:Asia/Calcutta
```

Swift:

```
let timezone = NSTimeZone.local
print(timezone.abbreviation)
print(timezone.name)
```

Comment: The OP wants the solution in Swift4.

Comment: let timezone = NSTimeZone.local

print(timezone.abbreviation)

print(timezone.name)